# MPI_Aint in MPI_(I)NEIGHBOR_ALLTOALLW() vs int in MPI_(I)ALLTOALLW()

Tags: mpi

With MPI3.0 neighborhood collective communications were introduced.
And in 2 of them (`MPI_NEIGHBOR_ALLTOALLW` and `MPI_INEIGHBOR_ALLTOALLW`) displacements (`sdispls` and `rdispls`) are arrays of `const MPI_Aint`. Contrariwise of how the same, but collective, funcions (`MPI_ALLTOALLW` and `MPI_ALLTOALLW`) are defined -arrays of `const int`.

Also considering what the MPI Standard v3.0 says about MPI_Aint (page 16):

> 2.5.6 Addresses
>
> Some MPI procedures use address arguments that represent an absolute address in the
>   calling program. The datatype of such an argument is MPI_Aint in C and
>   INTEGER (KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) in Fortran. These types must have the same width
>   and encode address values in the same manner such that address values in one language
>   may be passed directly to another language without conversion. There is the MPI constant
>   MPI_BOTTOM to indicate the start of the address range.

I still don't get the point and, if exist, the difference (in addition that `MPI_Aint` can't be negative) between `int` and `MPI_Aint`!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MPI_Aint` is a portable C data type that can hold memory addresses and it could be larger than the usual `int`. The policy of the MPI Forum is to not change the signature of existing MPI calls (as it could break existing applications - see [here](http://www.mpi-forum.org/mail_archive/mpi-21/Archive/msg00063.html)). Rather new calls are introduced that supersede the old ones. The rationale is that `int` worked well before LP64 64-bit architectures become popular at which point `int` could no longer be used to address the whole virtual address space of a single process. After this realisation some MPI calls got new versions in later versions that use `MPI_Aint` or `MPI_Count` (large integer type) instead of `int`. For example, `MPI_Get_count_x` supersedes `MPI_Get_count` and uses `MPI_Count` instead of `int`.

In this respect `MPI_Alltoallw` is an old call (it comes from MPI-2.0) and it retains its signature of using `int` offsets while `MPI_(I)Neighbor_alltoallw` is a new one (it comes with MPI-3.0) and it uses the address type in order to be able to work with data located (almost) anywhere in memory.

The same applies to the Fortran bindings.

Comment: With your answer and sizeof(MPI_Aint) that is 8 makes sense now, thanks :)

p.s: But why this explanation is not in the standard?

Comment: Usually such things are discussed on the publicly available mailing lists and discussion forums of the [MPI Forum](http://www.mpi-forum.org/).

Comment: The MPI standard is not meant to be a user guide, even if it appears so at times. See "Using MPI" books for explanations.